# Is IntelliJ idea's Javascript debug possible with Playframework?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, playframework-2.5

Is it possible to use IntelliJ IDEA's Javascript Debugger when developing Playframework app?

Comment: why not use the built in browser debugger?

Comment: i waste a lot of time searching for the file /  line when switching between ide and browser debugger.